# how to run Laravel API on line server

Tags: php, laravel

I have created `Laravel CRUD API` and it works fine in localhost(without .htaccess file), but it fails on the live server. When I send a request it returns `404 not found error`, or downloads a file depending on `.htaccess` content. How should I change `.htaccsess` file for makeing code to work.
this is my `.htaccess` file which returns not found error.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: **Very dangerous:** if your virtual host is pointed to root of project everyone from the internet will be able to read your .env file with credentials. `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]` says that your virtual host setting is that way.

Answer (score 1):

There is an 'official' htaccess that should provide you with the basic code to get this working.

See https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Then, simply make sure that the root points to `yourproject/public` so it can boot only from `yourproject/public/index.php`.

Comment: yes now it works, but with my .htaccess code it works too. is there any way to send requests without  `/public/` in it?

Comment: You nee to define your root directory as `public`. This is either some setting in your webhost panel like plesk/cpanel, or is defined in apache

Comment: I have deleted the project and clone it again from Github repo. Now it downloads `public/index.php` file with the same `.htaccess` file. Have I done any mistake in process

Comment: `public` should never be part of the URL. If it is then youre doing something wrong. This is server config and not code config.